# redis cluster nodes is reporting wrong self ip address

Tags: redis, redis-cluster, redisson

i have setup redis cluster on 3 ubuntu 20 nodes with identical network configs. (eno1 interface for management and enp1s0f1 for internal network )

in the /etc/redis/redis.conf i have it bind to the enp1s0f1 interface like so in the 3 nodes

```
bind 172.19.101.2x
```

i then create the redis cluster like so

```
redis-cli --cluster create 172.19.101.23:6379 172.19.101.24:6379 172.19.101.25:6379
```

the cluster gets created ok and cluster info also reports OK

but when i do cluster nodes it reports the management ip instead of the internal ip just for 1 node like so.

```
administrator@slave-node2:~$ redis-cli -h 172.19.101.24 cluster nodes
33c4484ca50aa7916b8727723f4eb5576c7b94ab 172.19.101.25:6379@16379 master - 0 1623764502745 4 connected 10923-16383
e099188cb0ae8bcc32ca7d81f0c8659a2b4ebb7b **10.110.3.166**:6379@16379 myself,master - 0 1623764500000 3 connected 5461-10922
3afa9cb15e166254a9f5182ba1b0df46137f954b 172.19.101.23:6379@16379 master - 0 1623764501741 2 connected 0-5460
```

So now when clients connect to this redis cluster they get this error - `Can't connect to master: redis://10.110.3.166:6379 with slot ranges: [[5461-10922]]`

BTW if i do redis-cli cluster nodes by connecting to other node in the cluster it reports ok like so

```
administrator@slave-node2:~$ redis-cli -h 172.19.101.25 cluster nodes
e099188cb0ae8bcc32ca7d81f0c8659a2b4ebb7b 172.19.101.24:6379@16379 master - 0 1623765101198 3 connected 5461-10922
3afa9cb15e166254a9f5182ba1b0df46137f954b 172.19.101.23:6379@16379 master - 0 1623765100194 2 connected 0-5460
33c4484ca50aa7916b8727723f4eb5576c7b94ab 172.19.101.25:6379@16379 myself,master - 0 1623765099000 4 connected 10923-16383
```

So question is

- why redis picking the management ip for this node ?
- is there anyway to restrict it to required ip / interface ?
- is there a way to change it in the cluster nodes ?

thanks for any pointers to this

Answer (score 1):

I think you can set the following in redis.conf .

```
cluster-announce-ip
```